# The deep reasons of admitting no global sections for a negative line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

We fix our discussion in the category of complex manifolds for convenience.

As well known,  a negative (i.e. its dual is positive) holomorphic line bundle admits no global sections while a positive line bundle has many global sections (up to tensoring many times with itself).

> **Questions.**
> **(1)** What is the  deep reasons of admitting no global sections for a
> negative line bundle?
> **(2)** How to understand the
> difference between positivity  and negativity of a line bundle?
> **(3)**
> Can someone give examples of line bundles which are
> positive somewhere and negative elsewhere and have many global
> sections?

Any explanation and comment is welcomed (you may tell us something from the information of topology or complex structure of the base manifold and the bundle itself or the hermitian structure of the bundle, etc.)

Comment: Very roughly speaking, a ''negative line bundle'' is something like ''minus (a positive rational multiple of) a hyperplane section'', so it cannot have global sections. Otherwise, the zero locus of such a section would be an effective divisor intersecting negatively a hyperplane section, that is absurd.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi This is intuitive, but... Why? :) As a "categorically minded" person I would rather expect something like "if a line bundle admits nonzero morphisms both from and into the trivial line bundle, then..."

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე: well, I guess that everyone has her/his own mental habits :-) I usually work with projective varieties, so the "negative intersection number" reason is the first one coming to my mind

Comment: Anyway, the "true analytic reason" is that, if a section $\sigma$ has only zeroes, then $1/\sigma$ has only poles. So $L$ and $L^*$ cannot have both a holomorphic, non constant section.

Comment: To complete მამუკა ჯიბლაძე's answer for the students out there: ... then we have non-zero maps $L \to \mathbb{C} \to L$ and $\mathbb{C} \to L \to \mathbb{C}$ which are necessarily isomorphisms if $X$ is compact ($\mathbb{C}$ has only scalar endomorphisms), so $L$ is isomorphic to the trivial line bundle. ($\mathbb{C}$ denotes the trivial line bundle).

Comment: Perhaps it is useful the following heuristics "the negative of a zero is a pole", so a negative bundle will have meromorphic sections whose inverses are regular sections, i.e. "negative regular sections".

Comment: 3) depends on what you mean by being positive/negative "somewhere" (something to do with Seshadri constants?), but I think the following idea works: take $\mathcal O(d)$ on $\mathbb P^n$ and let $p:X \to\mathbb P^n$ be the blowup of a point with exceptional divisor $E$. Then $L = p^*(\mathcal O(d))\otimes\mathcal O_X(mE)$ is as negative as you would like to make it along $E$ (by choosing $m$ large enough), but is as positive as you would like (by choosing $d$) along $X \setminus E$. And since every section of $\mathcal O(d)$ induces a distinct section of $L$, we have plenty of global sections.